# Example or Tutorial for creating for cloud code

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

I am doing coding with rest api method call for website which is using parse app (parse database). I need an example or
tutorial steps for creating  hello world example in parse cloud code.

Can anyone help me for this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read there Documentation? I find it very useful, have a look: 
https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#cloud-code